# how to check if a PHP script is running ? 

Tags: php, daemon

If I launch a PHP daemon in Windows with `popen` from a PHP script how do I check in a second time if that script is still running from a PHP script?

I'm with Apache, php as module

UPDATE:
process it's started with

```
popen('start /b php process.php', 'r');
```

Once this is launched in windows a php.exe process is started. How do I get that process PID to later check (it runs for hours) from another PHP script if that process is still running?

I read this [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) which is supposed to give the PID of the process launched along with `proc_get_status`  but with that same command I use with popen nothing happens

UPDATE: I noticed with the same command and proc_open a php.exe process does start but it closes just after the script that launched it ends and the PID returned by proc_get_status doesn't correspond to the Windows PID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of safely running processes with PHP and Windows:

### 1. Start background process using the WScript.Shell object

You can start the process using the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx) method of the WScript.Shell object, which is built-in to Windows. By varying the second parameter, you can make the window hidden, visible, minimized, etc. By setting the third parameter to false, Run does not wait for the process to finish executing. This code only works on Windows.  To find out more about COM, read [PHP's documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.com.php).

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C dir /S %windir%", 0, false);
```

### 2. Start background process using popen and pclose

This code should work on Linux and Windows.

```
pclose(popen("start \"bla\" \"" . $exe . "\" " . escapeshellarg($args), "r"));
```

### 3. Start background process with psexec

This method requires installing the freeware [pstools from sysinternals](http://www.sysinternals.com/):

```
exec("psexec -d blah.bat");
```

You can find out more information about it by reading this [brief tutorial](http://www.somacon.com/p395.php). I've used the first method before and it's always worked for me.

---

To find the PID of an existing process, I don't think you can use [`getmypid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php) or [`posix_getpid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpid.php) so you'll have to use `exec('tasklist');`. Alternatively, you can install [this extension](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/PHP_CLI%3a_PHP_INI#Extension_download) and follow [these instructions](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/PHP_CLI%3a_Process_Running).

Comment: I already know how to start a process what I need is
- get the PID of the process started
- know how to check if the process is still running using the PID

Comment: win32_ps should work but I couldn't find a way to make it work with php 5.3. That dll is for 5.2

Comment: I found here http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=win32ps_dll&version=1.0.1 the version that should work on 6.0 and older but it still doesn't get loaded (yes I put the extension in php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

use system() from php

and

Working with cmd.exe:

tasklist

If you have Powershell:

get-process

not tested. Or write your small console app with winapi calls